# vb.net Find String between two strings

Tags: vb.net, string, replace, find

I'm currently trying to make an app that replaces a value between two strings but the code I am using doesn't work, Anyone know how to do this properly?

```
Dim sSource As String = "64616D616765002D3100" 'String that is being searched
        Dim sDelimStart As String = "64616D61676500" 'First delimiting word
        Dim sDelimEnd As String = "00" 'Second delimiting word
        Dim nIndexStart As Integer = sSource.IndexOf(sDelimStart) 'Find the first occurrence of f1
        Dim nIndexEnd As Integer = sSource.IndexOf(sDelimEnd) 'Find the first occurrence of f2

        If nIndexStart > -1 AndAlso nIndexEnd > -1 Then '-1 means the word was not found.
            Dim res As String = Strings.Mid(sSource, nIndexStart + sDelimStart.Length + 1, nIndexEnd - nIndexStart - sDelimStart.Length) 'Crop the text between
            MessageBox.Show(res) 'Display
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("One or both of the delimiting words were not found!")
        End If
```

Comment: This is the error I get by the way "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Argument 'Length' must be greater or equal to zero."

Comment: I am assuming the error is for this?
nIndexEnd - nIndexStart - sDelimStart.Length ?

Why can't you use the replace function?

Comment: Yes and because the value I want to replace is always different but the strings before and after are always the same so i need to find the value and replace

Comment: Is the expected result string `2D31` in your example?

Comment: The errors meaning is literal "nIndexEnd - nIndexStart - sDelimStart.Length" these do not add upto above 0 (they need to), reading your code i think each value is 0.

Comment: @ Alex B yes thats correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim sSource As String = "64616D616765002D3100" 'String that is being searched
Dim sDelimStart As String = "64616D61676500" 'First delimiting word
Dim sDelimEnd As String = "00" 'Second delimiting word

MsgBox(sSource.Substring(InStr(sSource, sDelimStart) + sDelimStart.Length - 1, sSource.Length - sDelimStart.Length - sDelimEnd.Length))

'MsgBox(sSource.Substring(InStr(sSource, sDelimStart) + sDelimStart.Length - 1, InStr(sSource.Substring(InStr(sSource, sDelimStart) + sDelimStart.Length - 1, sSource.Length - (InStr(sSource, sDelimStart) + sDelimStart.Length - 1)), sDelimEnd) 'use this line for longer or different text
```

Comment: Sorry for the lack of explanation but i think by looking up the "Substring" function it's easy to work out how this line works. I took out your other code as I think it is unnecessary.

Comment: I take it back this ended up not working it only works if I use the exact code above but if i try to do something like have the source string be from a richtextbox thats has a huge string with that part in it but not be the whole string then it messes up

Comment: Could you give an example string?

Comment: To further explain im basically using this app to open a binary file convert it to hex then find the hex value of something like "damage.-1." (64616D616765002D3100) and reaplce the "-1" with "99" Here is the string of a binary file wich contains the above stringhttp://pastebin.com/VNaCXAsH

Comment: All 3 answers work for your question. You should of specify your question more properly.

Comment: Try using this line instead.
`MsgBox(sSource.Substring(InStr(sSource, sDelimStart) + sDelimStart.Length - 1, InStr(sSource.Substring(InStr(sSource, sDelimStart) + sDelimStart.Length - 1, sSource.Length - (InStr(sSource, sDelimStart) + sDelimStart.Length - 1)), sDelimEnd)`

You might want to split this up as long lines tend to take a bit more working out. You should have given an overview of what you were trying to do first, as I do think there maybe a better way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed for you:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim sSource As String = "64616D616765002D3100" 'String that is being searched
    Dim sDelimStart As String = "64616D61676500" 'First delimiting word
    Dim sDelimEnd As String = "00" 'Second delimiting word
    Dim nIndexStart As Integer = sSource.IndexOf(sDelimStart) 'Find the first occurrence of f1
    Dim nIndexEnd As Integer = sSource.IndexOf(sDelimEnd) 'Find the first occurrence of f2

    If nIndexStart > -1 AndAlso nIndexEnd > -1 Then '-1 means the word was not found.

        Dim res As String = Strings.Mid(sSource, sDelimStart.Length + 1, sSource.Length - (sDelimStart.Length + sDelimEnd.Length)) 'Crop the text between
        MessageBox.Show(res) 'Display
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("One or both of the delimiting words were not found!")
    End If
End Sub
```

Lets go over this line:

```
Dim res As String = Strings.Mid(sSource, sDelimStart.Length + 1, sSource.Length - (sDelimStart.Length + sDelimEnd.Length))

Strings.Mid(string to get middle part from, startIndex, lenght)
```

`String` you got.
`startIndex` is just `lenght` of first part plus one so `sDelimStart.Length + 1`
lenght is lenght of initial `string` minus (`lenght` of first part and last part combined)

```
sSource.Length - (sDelimStart.Length + sDelimEnd.Length)
```

Answer (score 0):

You had a couple of problems. See the code below:

```
    Dim sSource As String = "64616D616765002D3100" 'String that is being searched
    Dim sDelimStart As String = "64616D61676500" 'First delimiting word
    Dim sDelimEnd As String = "00" 'Second delimiting word
    Dim nIndexStart As Integer = sSource.IndexOf(sDelimStart) 'Find the first occurrence of f1
    Dim nIndexEnd As Integer = sSource.IndexOf(sDelimEnd, nIndexStart + sDelimStart.Length + 1) 'Find the first occurrence of f2

    If nIndexStart > -1 AndAlso nIndexEnd > -1 Then '-1 means the word was not found.
        Dim res As String = Strings.Mid(sSource, nIndexStart + sDelimStart.Length + 1, nIndexEnd - nIndexStart - sDelimStart.Length) 'Crop the text between
        MessageBox.Show(res) 'Display
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("One or both of the delimiting words were not found!")
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Function extract(source As String, start As String, ending As String)
    Return source.Substring(InStr(source, start, CompareMethod.Text) + start.Length - 1, InStr(source, ending) - (InStr(source, start, CompareMethod.Text) + start.Length))
End Function
```